Restoring photos from backup to PC causes issues with chronological display in apps
I needed to format my phone completely, so I connected it and copied all my photos and music to a location on my PC (running Linux if that is pertinent). After formatting my phone, I reconnected it to my PC and transferred everything back to it's original location. This appears to have modified the created timestamp of all the files to the time at which they were copied to my PC, which is wreaking havoc with how they are displayed, e.g. in Google messages app when I open my gallery to send a photo to someone, it's showing photos from 10 years ago at the top. The modified timestamp appears to be correct. Is there any way to rectify this issue at this point or have I put myself in a predicament?
Example file metadata:

P.S. I'm not sure if Android Enthusiasts is the right forum to pose this question in but I'm a bit lost. If this belongs elsewhere please point me in the right direction.

I may have found a solution to my own issue. I'm not sure if the created timestamp was the actual issue, or if the act of transferring the files back from my PC to my phone was modifying the modified timestamp in the process and causing the issue. Regardless, after playing around some more I decided to try creating a compressed tar of my photos directory on my PC and transferring that to my phone. Once on my phone, I used an application to decompress and extract the files which appears to have resolved the issue.
